# How to convert Javascript return value to String in Android

Tags: javascript, java, android

I am working in Android and I am new to this dev.

I learned and started to develop my app using Eclipse IDE.

I am showing a webView with a URL then I tried to call a JS function. This function returns a string value.

I am able to show it in alert, but I want to get it as string value. How can we do this?

I am getting type mismatch error on the line where I am converting to string.

### MY JS function:

```
function fing() {
    return "welcome today"
}
```

### My MainActivity.Java

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        generate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.generate);
        go = (Button) findViewById(R.id.go);
        webView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        generate.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {              
            @Override
            public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view, String url, String message,JsResult result) {
                        Log.d("LogTag from js call method", message);
                        result.confirm();
                        return true;
               }
        });     

        go.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                go.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                generate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                webView.loadUrl("myUrl");       
            }
        }); 

        generate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {    
                webView.loadUrl("javascript:alert(fing())");      
                String retStr = webView.loadUrl("javascript:alert(fing())");//Here type mis match error
                System.out.println(retStr)              
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not do this in a way you tried above.

For making JS calls which returns a value from that function, Change the generate.setOnClickListener code to the same as below,

```
    generate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {    
            webView.loadUrl("javascript:alert(fing())");  
        }
    });
```

Then you should change the following part also to get that return value to be assigned to String,

```
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {              
        @Override
        public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view, String url, String message,JsResult result) {
                    Log.d("LogTag from js call method", message);
                    str = message;
                    result.confirm();
                    return true;
           }
    });
```

This should be already in your Logcat console, because your code already has that.

If not, you need to double check the webChromeClient if it initiated again in somewhere in your Activity for the same webView object.

### Note:

You have to create str (String) variable in the Activity, which is assigned in the onJSAlert method.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you exchange string values between webview javascript environment to java android by using javascript bridge. please look at the example

http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html

if you cannot use above javascript bridge

give try on

javascript ->

```
function fing() {
return "welcome today"
}
```

Webview loading script  `javascript:alert(fing().stringyfy())"`